# PySNMP not returning data from generator

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am experiencing very strange behaviour with PySNMP. I want to get PoE info from a Cisco 2960 using the `POWER-ETHERNET-MIB` mib. When I run the following code:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

data = {}

for (error_indication,
     error_status,
     error_index,
     values) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                        CommunityData('community', mpModel=0),
                        UdpTransportTarget(('SWITCH', 161), timeout=10),
                        ContextData(),
                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('POWER-ETHERNET-MIB', 'pethMainPseEntry').addAsn1MibSource('http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@')),
                        lexicographicMode=False, lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True):

    print('""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""')
    print(values)
    print(error_indication)
    print(error_status)
    print(error_index)
    print('""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""')
    for v in values:
        print(v)
        oid, text = str(v).split('=')
        data[''.join(oid.strip())] = ''.join(text.strip().strip("'"))
print(data)
```

I only get the empty dictionary as output. Not even an error. I have been breaking my head over this, what could be the reason for this?

EDIT:
relevant stacktrace output

```
`;pyasn1.type.error.ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535)), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255)), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 32)) failed at: ValueConstraintError("ValueSizeConstraint(1, 32) failed at: ValueConstraintError(b'traphost.community.172.20.1.1.1',)",) at SnmpAdminString`
```

Comment: You mean you never enter the loop body? That could happen if your agent does not serve any OIDs in the `pethMainPseEntry` subtree. What happens if you set `lexicographicMode=True`?

Comment: @IlyaEtingof Exactly. With `lexicographicMode=True` the loop body is entered, but an error is raised as soon as it reaches the OID I'm trying to get. All data before is printed out. I cannot post the stacktrace as it contains sensitive information and is about 150 lines long, but basically it boils down to a `valueconstrainterror` (relevant part in OP)

Comment: Updated my answer. Note that your community string is possibly leaked in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The generators implementing GETNEXT and GETBULK queries return a matrix (2-D array) of variable-bindings:

```
[ [ var_bind, var_bind, ... ],
  [ var_bind, var_bind, ... ],
             ...            ]
```

Where each row represents response variable-bindings positionally matching the variables in request. In case of GETNEXT, no more than just a single row could ever be returned, but GETBULK is dufferent -- it can produce many rows in response.

Since GETBULK and GETNEXT are very similar, pysnmp supports the same generalized call signature for both generators.

So to make sense out of the GETNEXT response you need to iterate over `values` (rows) and then iterate over each row (e.g. columns). I think your code misses the second iteration.

```
for row in values:
    for column in row:
        oid, value = column
        data[oid] = str(value)
```

Here's the [example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations.html#walk-whole-mib) script.

EDIT:

Once we know the kind of error occurred, I think the cause may be that the `communityIndex` parameter is by default initialized from `communityName`. Trouble is that unlike `communityName` it is size-constrained to 32 octets (by SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB definition).

So my suggestion is to explicitly pass `communityIndex` to `CommunityData` initializer:

```
CommunityData('my-short-id', 'my-unbelievably-long-community-string', mpModel=0)
```

Alternatively, you can just shrink your `communityName` to fit 32 charters.

Here's [the doc](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.hlapi.CommunityData) on `CommunityData`.

Comment: I should have mentioned this: For some reason the print statement never get executed. Which is strange. I use this exact same function for many other GETs and they all worked